# My Android is messing up my text Views

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

i'm using relative layout and I'm trying to figure out why my textViews are messing up. Here is how it starts <sup>(click to enlarge)</sup>

[image]

But then when the values star coming in it looks like this

[image]

This is my xml.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/inputVariables"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
    android:text="@string/startingPoint"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/calculatedPoint"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/speed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/heading"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/oneSecond" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="@string/tenMilliSecond" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/heading" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="@string/speed" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/oneSecondCalculatedPointLongitude"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/oneSecondCalculatedLatitude"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="@string/latitude" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/oneHundredMillisecondLatitude"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/oneSecondCalculatedPointLongitude"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/oneHundredMillisecondLatitude"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/oneHundredMillisecondLatitude"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/heading"
    android:text="@string/latitude" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/oneHundredMillisecondLongitude"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/oneHundredMillisecondLatitude"
    android:layout_below="@+id/oneHundredMillisecondLatitude"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/oneHundredMillisecondLongitude"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/oneHundredMillisecondLongitude"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/heading"
    android:text="@string/longitude" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/heading"
    android:text="@string/longitude" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/heading"
    android:text="@string/longitude" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/startingPointLatitude"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/speed"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/startingPointLatitude"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/startingPointLatitude"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/heading"
    android:text="@string/latitude" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/startingPointLongitude"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/startingPointLatitude"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/oneSecondCalculatedLatitude"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/startingPointLongitude"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/heading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

This is my Code thats changing the textView.texts

```
                    Location predicationPoint = DOTGpsAppUtils.predictionAlgorithm(latitude, longitude, 1, 100);

                double predictionLongitude = (longitude + predicationPoint.getLongitude())/2;
                double predictionLatitude = (latitude + predicationPoint.getLatitude())/2;

                TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oneHundredMillisecondLatitude);
                textView.setText(Double.valueOf(predictionLatitude).toString());

                textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oneSecondCalculatedPointLongitude);
                textView.setText(Double.valueOf(predictionLongitude).toString());


                if(x == 9)
                {
                    longitude = predictionLongitude;
                    latitude = predictionLatitude;
                }

                System.out.println(x);

                ++x;
            }while(x < 10);

            TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startingPointLongitude);
            textView.setText(Double.valueOf(location.getLongitude()).toString());

            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startingPointLatitude);
            textView.setText(Double.valueOf(location.getLatitude()).toString());

            textView =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oneSecondCalculatedPointLongitude);
            textView.setText(Double.valueOf(longitude).toString());

            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.oneSecondCalculatedLatitude);
            textView.setText(Double.valueOf(latitude).toString());
```

Comment: Looks to me like you're setting text to the wrong Views. That said, you've given us NOTHING to work with. Post some code.

Comment: what do you need? I'm pretty sure I set the texts right sorry I'm new to android I'm better with iOS haha

Comment: Check that the textviews have unique id's and that you are allocating text to the correct textView Id

Comment: @MichaelChoi If u want to get helped post ur code ..It doesnot matter whether ur expert of IOs or whatever

Comment: Yes that have unique text view Ids. I renamed textViews in the xml myself. I'm certain that they are hooked up correctly

Comment: @MichaelChoi and plz respect other member do not make fun of anyone. kcoppock is a senior with 36292 reputation point..mind it

Comment: I meant no disrespect I just don't know where to start to even get help.

Comment: Um, I don't think there was any making fun. @.@ Anyway, what IDE are you using? If you're using Eclipse, maybe you should clean and rebuild your project. It seems like all of your IDs should be mapped correctly.

Comment: Yeah That was the answer @kcoppock. Just needed to be cleaned thnx a ton ROFL.. is there a way to give you more reputation.. apparently it's a really big deal, I never knew HAHA

Comment: It's really not. :P I'd highly recommend giving IntelliJ IDEA 12 (Community Edition) a shot to replace Eclipse. I switched like a year ago and have never looked back (and I've converted all my colleagues to it as well.) :) (http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/)

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like your assigning the values to wrong TextViews.

Comment: this ain't a answer, rather a comment :)

Comment: Sorry I cant add it as a comment since I'm low in rep. :)